# AWS and Datagrid: Create S3 bucket using C# and view current buckets in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, datagrid

Firstly, I want to apologize for my poor wording, as I am unsure how to go about creating this. I am still fairly new to both WPF and AWS, so please bear with me.

I have a WPF that I want to create buckets in. I have already created the GUI and downloaded AWS. Now what I have to do is view the different buckets in AWS. I would also like to create buckets and showcase the creation date for them.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the datagrid, and here is the code for the Bucket page:

```
<Window x:Class="LabAssignment1.CreateBucket"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LabAssignment1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CreateBucket" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtBucketName" Margin="169,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="343"/>
        <Label Content="Bucket Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Create Bucket" x:Name="btnCreateBucket" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="534,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="150" Click="btnCreateBucket_Click"/>
        <DataGrid  x:Name="dgBucket" Margin="0,130,0,70">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bucket Name" Width="380" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Creation Date" Width="*"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="235,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.291,0.373" Width="206"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please do not feel the need to send code for it. I would much prefer some general guidance for how I can solve the problem. If you require more, please let me know

Thank you, and sorry if I explained it wrong

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems you want to use C# to get buckets in your account and display them in a UI.

To perform this task in C#, you need to use the **AWS SDK for .NET** and the S3 .NET Service Client. You can use this Service Client to get the S3 buckets that you have and other S3 operations.

To learn how to work with the AWS SDK for .NET, see the DEV Guide.

[What is the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

To get buckets (and other S3 operations using AWS SDK for .NET), see the code examples in Github here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/S3

Comment: I appreciate this, however I already did everything here

Comment: If you question is more about how to set a WPF data grid with data returned from a backend - that is a different type of question. To get data from an AWS Service in a .NET program - you always use the AWS SDK for .NET.